# How can I display a User Email? im using Codeigniter + Tank Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I can display the username correctly but i want to display the email address.

I have codeigniter 2.1.4 with Tank Auth 1.0.9, i have this:

```
Hi, <strong><?php echo $username; ?></strong>
<br />
Your email address: <?php echo $email; ?><br />
```

I'm getting this error:

Your email address:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: email

Filename: views/welcome_message.php

Line Number: 70

The username shows up correctly but email doesnt show up.

Any suggestions?

Thank you guys!

Comment: how you are passing the data to the view? look like you are not passing the `[email]` address to the view

Comment: $data['user_id'] = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
   $data['username'] = $this->tank_auth->get_username();
   $this->load->view('welcome/welcome_message', $data);

Answer (score 0):

Tank Auth don't set the email on session so they did not provided any function to get email like `get_username`.

so what you have to get user details form db you can use `users model` to get user info like this

```
$user = $this->users->get_user_by_username($this->tank_auth->get_username());
$data['email'] = $user->email; //set the email on data that you was missing
```

Comment: what are you getting in `$user` print_r($user) to see the data